# php unit test mockery set property from method

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm learning php unit test. I've question; how to set property value from method? Here is my example code:

```
class Variables 
{

    public $date;

    public function setDate(\DateTime $date) {
        $this->date = $date;
    }

}

class Process 
{
    public function process(Variables $var) {
        if ($var->date->getTimeStamp() > 0) {
            return 'success';
        }

        return 'failed';
    }
}

class ProcessTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase 
{
    public function testProcess() 
    {
        $mock = \Mockery::mock('Variables');
        $mock->date = new \DateTime();
        $procy = new Process();
        $actual = $procy->process($mock);
        $this->assertEquals('success', $actual);
    }  
}
```

Like in the codes above, I know, I can set property `date` by:

```
$mock->date = new \DateTime();
```

because it's public.

What if the property `date` is private or protected? How to set from mockery? I tried to do something like this, but got an error.

```
$mock->shouldReceive('setDate')->once()->andSet('date', new \DateTime());
```

Sample class that describes my question :

```
class Calculation {

    protected $a;
    protected $b;
    protected $c;

    public function __construct() {
        ;
    }

    public function setA($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function setB($b) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }

    public function call() {
        $this->c = (int) $this->a + (int) $this->b;
    }

    public function getC() {
        return $this->c;
    }

}
```

I need your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably add an accessor to `Variables`, use it in `Process::process()` instead of accessing the `public` property, and thus, you would have to set up an expectation that the accessor is called when you invoke `Process::process()`:

```
$date = new \DateTime();

$variables = \Mockery::mock('Variables');

$variables->shouldReceive('getDate')->withNoArgs()->andReturn($date);

$process = new Process();

$this->assertSame('success', $process->process($variables));
```

For reference, see:

- http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html

Comment: but I don't have method `getDate` in my class. If I have, probably I just need to do `$mock->shouldReceive('getDate')->andReturn($date);`

Comment: Depends on whether you want to assert that `setDate()` is invoked with `$date`, @kelaskakap. If it's not important for your test, then you don't need to set up any expectations for it.

Comment: yes I don't need expectiation from `setDate` method. I just want to know, how to set property `date` (if it's private or protected) from method `setDate` using Mockery in unit test.   Because I don't have method `getDate` in my class.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible with Mockery, but if it is, then it is a design failure (in my opinion). You should only test the public API.

Comment: @kelaskakap How do you want to access a `private` or `protected` field of an object from an object of a different kind (without reflection)? It's not possible without an accessor.

Comment: @_localheinz do you think this class is testable? how would you create unit test for this class? (I update my question, please take a look at Class Calculation)

Comment: @kelaskakap Yes, `Calculation` is surely testable! Question is whether you a) want to test it as it is, or b) drive the design through tests, or c) improve the design before you retroactively add tests. What do you think?